# Bootstrap display flex mobile and desktop view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using flex layout. On desktop is everything good, but on mobile view is text is too small. I try d-md-flex but is not working. Maybe I must change h-100?

jsfiddle.net/cva13dhu

Comment: Pls show your code

Comment: Please go through this and learn how to post a minimal-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cva13dhu/ -i cant add code by codesnippet :( you must get booststrap script

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>